# Why is Jupyter Notebook taking so long to load?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Seemingly out of nowhere, one of my Jupyter Notebook .ipynb files now takes forever to open, to the point where I receive Chrome notifications saying that the page is unresponsive. If I wait it out it does open, however. Once it does open, though, it fails to have any of its nbextensions applied. For example, I can now no longer use codefolding. The notebook also seems to have a fair amount of lag when I try to scroll or edit cells.

The file is 556 kB and does have its output cleared (as I've noticed that being an issue for others), though it does contain a few thousand lines of code. I'm able to open smaller files (391 kB) with far fewer lines of code quickly, with all my selected nbextensions active, and with no lag.

Why would this marginally larger file have such issues? What can I do about this?

---

EDIT:
I have noticed that when opening the file in question, my Anaconda Prompt outputs the following:

```
404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js
```

This error does not pop up when I'm running the smaller file. I'm confused as to why this error would be conditional on the file being ran.

---

EDIT 2:
The following link seems to be quite related to my issue:

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/822

Basically, it seems like the issue is simply that nbextensions don't play well with larger files. I'm going to try splitting up the code into multiple files and hope the core file becomes small enough for this to work out better.

Answer (score 0):

See Edit 2.

Simple solution - just make the file smaller. Everything is working as expected now.